# UnityEditor: System.ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint

Tags: unity-game-engine, custom-attributes, unity-editor

I'm trying to implement displaying the properties of an object added to an ObjectField via an attribute. Through a custom editor, I can, but I'm tired of creating an editor for each new class. I want through attribute.

Code for attribute:

```cs
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class DisplayPropertiesAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public DisplayPropertiesAttribute() { }
}
```

Code for drawer:

```cs
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(DisplayPropertiesAttribute))]
    public class DisplayPropertiesDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        private Editor editor;
        private bool foldout;

        /// <summary>
        /// Overrides GUI drawing for the attribute
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position"><see cref="Rect"/> fields to activate validation</param>
        /// <param name="property">Serializedproperty the object</param>
        /// <param name="label">Displaу field label</param>
        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {// Check if this is reference type property
            if (property.propertyType != SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference)
            {
                // If field is not reference, show error message.            
                var style = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.objectField);
                style.normal.textColor = Color.red;

                // Display label with error message
                EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label, new GUIContent($"{property.propertyType} is not a reference type"), style);
                return;
            }

            // If there is already an editor, add a foldout icon
            if (editor) { foldout = EditorGUI.Foldout(position, foldout, new GUIContent()); }

            // Start blocking change checks
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            // Display a ObjectField
            EditorGUI.ObjectField(position, property, label);
            // If changes were made to the contents of the field,
            // or the reference is empty, there is an editor,
            // or the reference is there but there is no editor
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck() || (property.objectReferenceValue ^ editor))
            {
                // Create an editor for the object pointed to by the reference, even if reference is empty
                editor = Editor.CreateEditor(property.objectReferenceValue);
            }

            // If foldout is true and the Editor exists
            if (foldout && editor)
            {
                // Draw the properties of an object in a frame
                GUILayout.BeginVertical(EditorStyles.helpBox);
                editor.OnInspectorGUI();
                GUILayout.EndVertical();
            }
        }
    }
```

When scrolling (when the field is hidden behind the screen frame), an error occurs:
`System.ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint`
The properties are not displayed. Instead, empty space...

There is still a problem with displaying arrays, but for now I want to get rid of at least this error.

I wrapped the error in a try-catch and just hid the properties, but it looks bad.

```cs
                // Draw the properties of an object in a frame
                try
                {
                    GUILayout.BeginVertical(EditorStyles.helpBox);
                    editor.OnInspectorGUI();
                    GUILayout.EndVertical();
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentException e)
                {
                    foldout = false;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that within a **PropertyDrawer** you can not use the automatically layouted API from `GUILayout` or `EditorGUILayout` but only the absolute `Rect` API from `GUI` and `EditorGUI` always passing in the according start position and dimensions.

You would need to

- Calculate the required total height to display the nested content
- Add this height to the `public override float GetPropertyHeight` which will tell the Inspector to reserve according `Rect` to draw your property
- Pass on the according `Rect` reserved for the sub-editor into the `editor` and draw at given position and dimensions

=> You can not simply use the default editor to achieve this as it operates in the auto-layout system which can not be used by PropertyDrawers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to get property output from a sub-editor? Or will it have to be calculated separately for each type of object?

Comment: Since the editor afaik doesn't know the final height until it finishes executing the entire `OnInpectorGUI` call there is no way for you do pre-calculate it without already drawing the content